# Using Backgroundworker with a Timer

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I've looked in many places for this but still haven't found a solution. What I'm trying to achieve is being able to use BackgroundWorker on a timed basis. Here's an example:

```
    public Main()
    {

        isDbAvail = new BackgroundWorker();
        isDbAvail.DoWork += isOnline;
        isDbAvail.RunWorkerCompleted += rewriteOnlineStatus; 


    }

    private void rewriteOnlineStatus(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subs.Connection connection = new Subs.Connection();
        changeStatus(connection.isDbAvail());
    }

    private void isOnline(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checking database connection");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
        }
    }

    public void changeStatus(bool status)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            serverStatusVal.Text = "Connected";
            serverStatusVal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            serverStatusVal.Text = "Not connected";
            serverStatusVal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

What's happening here is that the `isOnline` method checks if there is a connection to the database (just an example) every 8 seconds and changes the text accordingly. What I've noticed though, is that the while loop inside the `isOnline` method causes the `rewriteOnlineStatus` method never to fire because it runs indefinitely. Is there another workaround to this?

Comment: Check out `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`

Comment: Why aren't you using a `Timer` which executes every 8 seconds?

Comment: @yuval, because checking the database connection will block until it times out if the connection is down.

Comment: @Blogrebeard then he can use `System.Threading.Timer` which executes in a background thread.

Comment: Actually, it seems OP is actually checking the connection in the UI thread anyway.. seems like he's trying to use the BackgroundWorker like a timer.

Comment: In theory, I need to check if the connection is still available after 8 seconds. If it is, tell the user it is, if it's not, block certain aspects of the application. One issue I had was Cross-Thread errors that kept coming up when a status changed...

Comment: @Dimitri your problems seem to much to fit in a single question. Go one by one.

Comment: @L.B I don't think it's a lot to fit in one question; I only have one problem at hand. Cross-Thread came up with Timers and stuff, but my problem lies within backgroundworker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`, and check connectivity in the background thread.

Something like this:

```
public Main()
{
    isDbAvail = new BackgroundWorker();
    isDbAvail.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    isDbAvail.DoWork += isOnline;
    isDbAvail.ProgressChanged += rewriteOnlineStatus; 
    isDbAvail.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void rewriteOnlineStatus(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    changeStatus((bool)e.UserState);
}

private void isOnline(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking database connection");
        Subs.Connection connection = new Subs.Connection();
        isDbAvail.ReportProgress(0, connection.isDbAvail);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
    }
}
```

Now the BackgroundWorker is doing the work, and reporting back to the UI thread via `ProgressChanged`.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing 0 and ignoring it; the result is passed in the UserData object. This is the overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx

Comment: Great! One more thing: if your `Subs.Connection` implements `IDisposable`, you should wrap the code that uses it in a `using` statement. Otherwise, you may run into problems after a while since you're creating a new connection every 8 seconds.

Comment: Agreed, it was one of the first things I looked into when writing that section!